# Add the number of pending notifications to the moderator inbox

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-tools, top-bar

When there are unread inbox items, the number of unread items appears in a red rectangle over the square bra icon.

When there are unread achievements dropdown items, the number of unread achivements appears in a green rectangle over the bar chart icon.

When there are unread moderator attention items, the gray diamond turns blue (dodger blue?). Not only is the contrast poor, but useful information is missing (how behind am I?).

[image: empty]
turns into
[image: not emtpy]

(The contrast looks slightly better when the diamond isn't in the middle of a black bar, but it's still not strikingly visible.)

Please show the number of unread moderator items (in a blue rectangle, I guess). This would have the added benefit of making the fact that there are pending items more visible.

Comment: *jealous that you don't have a flag indicator next to it*

Comment: @animuson On [french.se], we've had about 500 flags. No, not today. Since the beginning of the site two years ago.

Comment: Alternate request (which I don't like): [change the color](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210425/change-the-color-of-the-moderator-inbox-diamond).