# Change the color of the moderator inbox diamond

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-tools, top-bar

Currently the diamond that notifies you of changes to the moderator inbox changes its color from [grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PbIJ.png) to [blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYKtz.png).

*[Grey Diamond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PbIJ.png):*
[image]


*[Blue Diamond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYKtz.png):*
[image]

I think the blue blends far too well into the design of the top bar, the contrast is too low. Until I was told in chat that it changes color, I didn't even notice the change.

I would really like it if the color changes to a more visible color (eg red).

Comment: Yes. Agree with this. Plus red is the fastest colour too, so that's the best one.

Comment: Red is also already used for the normal comment notifications, so it would fit quite well.

Comment: Does `<blink>` still work? That'd be great for this situation. Especially for SO/MSO mods. It'll turn the top bar into a little disco.

Comment: I'd prefer to make it more visible by [adding the number of unread notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210049/add-the-number-of-pending-notifications-to-the-moderator-inbox) but retain the color (or only tweak it a little) so that it's distinct from the other notifications on the top bar.

Comment: @JonW I'm afraid you'll have to implement your own <blink> tag. May I suggest doing so with a Java applet to maximize the violence people will visit upon you? :)

Comment: @JonW - Your first comment seriously blows my mind. I mean, I've studied the science behind colors in Physics, so I get it, but from a design perspective, I've never thought about picking a color based solely on its wavelength to determine where the user looks first. I'm going to need to go contemplate this for awhile...

Comment: Yes please. It takes me way too long to notice the change.

Comment: I missed some notifications because I didn't noticed the color +1

Comment: I'm in a similar boat as jmsfg -- I'm so used to a blue diamond everywhere ***else***, that I didn't realize the "default" color was gray.