# Inconsistent coloring of moderator inbox (desktop vs. mobile)

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, mobile-web, top-bar

This is the well-known [blue diamond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210425/295232) indicating that there's something in the ♦ moderator inbox:

[image]

However, when I look at the top bar in Safari on iOS (11.4), it's *green*:

[image]

<sub>(This might be solved with the new responsive design, but it looks like a small fix which could be done earlier.)</sub>

FWIW, today's *orange* diamond is not even shown at all:

[image]

Comment: Its also orange in places no? ;p

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how the orange diamond is shown on mobile. They are quite rare ...

Comment: I can't reproduce... Oh... wait.... I'm not a moderator on any site !!!

Comment: Even for moderators it can be hard to reproduce, depending on the # of new questions on Meta and the mod messages the team sends.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I could check it today but the orange diamond isn't even shown.